# Calculating the Radius of a Charged Particle in a Magnetic Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, geometry

Let us say that a particle moves in a circular motion with a constant speed $\lvert v\rvert$ and that it begins at the bottom of its circular motion of radius $R$ (i.e. it begins at $(x, y) = (0, -R)$ and moves through $(R, 0), (0, R)$ and $(-R, 0)$). Given that the $x$- and $y$- components of the particle's velocity are $v_x = 1.4\ 10^5\mathrm{\frac ms}$ and $v_y = 2.5\ 10^5\mathrm{\frac ms}$ respectively at the $x$-coordinate $D = .53\ \mathrm m$, the original problem is calculate the radius of the loop.

[image]

The $B$ in the figure is just the magnetic field within that region, as this is a magnetism problem.

The solution to this problem is that $\sin \theta = \frac {v_y}v = \frac DR$, so $R = \frac {D}{\sin \theta} = D \frac v{v_y}$. However, I do not understand why $\sin \theta = \frac {v_y}v$ AND $\frac DR$ both. In other words, my question is, why is $\sin \theta$ also equal to $\frac DR$? It seems to me that the angles, and therefore the sines of the angles, would not be the same, but the solution says this is. Can anyone offer some insight? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity $v$ is always tangential to the trajectory of the particle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's just a geometric problem. Remember that in an circular motion the speed (in this case of the charge) is always tangent to the circumference.
Also remember that the segment connecting the center of the circumference and the point of tangency of a tangent line (this segment is indeed the radius of the circumference) is always perpendicular to that line.

Now look at the following picture:
[image]

You can immediately realize that 
$$sin\theta = \frac{v_y}{v_x} = \frac{D}{R}$$
and this is true for every point belonging to the circumference